# Why does removing an audio track in Handbrake reduce volume?

Tags: audio, mkv, handbrake, volume

I am transcoding a couple of blu-ray videos using Handbrake (v1.2.2). I play the resulting MKV containers mainly using Video LAN Client (VLC).

Often a blu-ray has several audiotracks that are basically identical in content, but different encoding. Since I'm transcoding all audio to AAC, all but one appear redundant to me, and I'd like to get rid of them. Doing so, however, severely reduces volume of the remaining tracks, in the order of magnitude of 10 to 12db! I'd like to understand this behaviour.

For instance there are four tracks in two languages, each language in DTS and DTS-HD MA. If I keep all tracks (transcoding them to AAC), the play-back volume is preserved. If in Handbrake (under the Audio/Track List section) I delete any one of the four tracks ("delete" meaning exempt from transcoding), the transcode result plays back with each of the remaining three audio tracks with reduced volume. Since this appears to be global, I thought maybe a global replay gain tag was reset. But checking the MKV container with MKVToolNix I cannot find any replay gain tag, neither global, nor track-specific, in the result of any of the experiments. If I do include all tracks, however, such that the full volume is retained, I can afterwards use MKVToolNix to remove (re-multiplex) the undesired audio without affecting volume - a slightly laborious workaround, but I really would like to understand what's going on.

The Handbrake settings for the AAC are the default (Bitrate 192kb/s, 5.1ch, sample rate as in source, extra gain and DRC off. Interestingly, I found the extra gain setting, when using it, does not effect the volume.

Edit:
I found the behaviour to be not as consistent as I thought, in fact, I've come to believe that I found a bug. Apparently, leaving the extra gain off (it is displayed as 0dB), does not leave the volume untouched, but in fact applies a more or less random gain (apparently triggered by deleting audio tracks), as can be confirmed in the activity log. Activating the extra gain, and explicitly setting it to 0dB makes Handbrake behave as expected.

Since StackExchange is not a place for bug reports, I wonder if I should delete this question? Please advise.